# Ambivalent groups have even order

Tags: group-theory

An ambivalent group is a group $G$ such that for each $x$ in $G$ there is a $g\in G$ such that $g^{-1}xg=x^{-1}$. Such a group can be characterised by the fact that all its irreducible characters over $\mathbb{C}$ take real values.

I want to show that a nontrivial finite ambivalent group has even order. So far I could only derive the following:

- The centre $Z(G)$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group. This is simply because if $x\in Z(G)$ then $x=x^{-1}$.
- If $G$ has odd order then $G$ is a perfect group. This is because if $G'\neq G$ is nontrivial then $G/G'$ is a nontrivial elementary abelian $2$-group and then we can just derive that $G$ is of even order. If $G'$ is trivial then $G$ is abelian and again it should have even order.

Is this the right way to approach this? Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a nontrivial finite ambivalent group. Pick $x\in G$ with $x\neq 1$. Since $G$ is ambivalent, there is $g\in G$ with $g^{-1}xg = x^{-1}$. Then $g^{-1}x^{-1}g = x$, so for all natural numbers $n$, $$g^{-n}xg^n = \begin{cases} x^{-1}&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\ x&\text{if $n$ is even}.\end{cases}$$

If $g$ has even order, then $G$ has even order by Lagrange, and we're done. Otherwise, $g$ has odd order, so $g^{n} = g$ for some even $n$. Then $$x^{-1} = g^{-1}xg  = g^{-n}xg^{n} = x,$$ so $x$ has order $2$, and again $G$ has even order by Lagrange.

Comment: How did you get the last equality, namely, $g^{-n}xg^n=x$?

Comment: @Shaun by the first paragraph ($n$ is even).

Comment: Ah, yes, I see; it holds for arbitrary $n$. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaun Yes. I made a small edit to clarify this point.